# Проблема запуска внешнего bash скрипта из PHP

Tags: php, bash, exec

Есть php скрипт, вот кусок кода из него

```
        $uploaddir = "/tmp/";
        $updatedir = "/home/andy/test/";
        $update_script_path = "/home/andy/updater.sh";
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['arch']['name']);
        $uploadfile = str_replace(' ', '', $uploadfile);
        if ($_FILES['arch']['tmp_name'] != "" && copy($_FILES['arch']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $update_script_path = escapeshellarg($update_script_path);
            $uploadfile = escapeshellarg($uploadfile);
            $updatedir = escapeshellarg($updatedir);
            $commandline = $update_script_path." ".$uploadfile." ".$updatedir;
            //echo "<pre>" . ($res = system($commandline)) . "</pre>";
            echo "<pre>" . ($res = shell_exec($commandline)) . "</pre>";
            //echo "<pre>" . ($res = exec($commandline)) . "</pre>";
            //echo "<pre>" . ($res = system("/bin/sh -c /home/andy/updater.sh")) . "</pre>";
        }
```

Пусть не смущают закоментированные строки запуска, это я просто пробовал различные варианты.
Есть простой bash скрипт, права на его выполнение установлены

```
#!/bin/sh
tar -xvf $1 -C $2
```

Т.е. php скрипт принимает файл от пользователя, формирует командную строку для запуска bash скрипта. Проблема в том, что bash скрипт не отрабатывает, в bash скрипт оба аргумента передаются корректно, я проверял это выводя из bash скрипта

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

bash скрипт должен распаковать файл который пользователь передал через форму в заданную директорию, однако ничего не происходит. Если я из консоли вызываю свой bash скрипт "вручную"

```
root@test-device:/home/andy # ./updater.sh /tmp/files.tar.gz /home/andy/test/
```

То все отлично отрабатывает, я как видите из кода php скрипта игрался с различными вариантами, но успеха не получил (((

Comment: Укажите полный путь до tar в скрипте

Answer (score -1):

У Вас вероятно проблема с недостаточными правами доступа у пользователя, из под которого у вас запущен http-сервер и который обрабатывает запрос к указанному скрипту.

Проверьте и добавьте права:

- для папки `/home/andy/test` - на запись
- для файла скрипта `/home/andy/updater.sh` - на выполнение

Comment: *Если я из консоли вызываю свой bash скрипт "вручную", то все отлично отрабатывает.*

Comment: @Ипатьев, в ответе я написал про права для пользователя,  из под ко которого запущен http-сервер. А ТС пишет, что все работает верно, из консоли  под пользователем andy.